# How to make Dio handle the HTTP 302 code as a regular HTTP code and not an error ? (Http status error [302])

Tags: http, redirect, dart, flutter, http-status-code-302

Upon sending login data to a remote URL, the website returns a 302 along with the proper login Cookies. When processing it with http or HttpClient, the status code 302 is processed as good, however with Dio it's considered as an error.

**How to make Dio handle the HTTP 302 code as a regular HTTP code and not an error ?**

Code

```
Dio dio = new Dio();
dio.options.contentType = ContentType('application','x-www-form-urlencoded');
dio.post(urlLogin, data: data).then((Response resp){
  print('-----Login-----');
  List<String> headers = resp.headers['set-cookie'];
  headers.forEach((h) => print(h));
});
```

Stack Trace

```
Unhandled exception:
DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [302]
#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1112:29)
#1      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#2      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#3      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:391:30)
#4      _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:165:12)
```

Comment: My bad, did some bad research, voted to close it in favor of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537500/flutter-handle-status-code-302-in-post-request?rq=1

Comment: 0

i got a similar problem and i solved it with adding header with "Accept":"application/json" . henceforth it will only return json data otherwise it will prompt to redirect with html url.