# Unable to add header for post method in dio in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dio

I'm using **dio: ^3.0.4**. Any one please help me to find the solution for adding header. here my code:

```
FormData formData = 
    new FormData.fromMap({"files": await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath.path, filename: 'photo')
          });
```

---

```
  Response response = await dio.post("***********",
    data: formData,
    onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
      print("$sent $total");
    },
    options: Options(
      headers: {
        "authorization": "*************"
      },
      followRedirects: false,
      validateStatus: (status) {
        return status <= 500;
      }
    ),
  );
```

When i print the header.

> print(response.headers);

**Result:**

> flutter: content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 connection: close
>   cache-control: no-cache, private transfer-encoding: chunked date: Thu,
>   07 Nov 2019 14:29:02 GMT server: Apache/2.4.18

Comment: You are printing the response headers, which look basically correct for response headers. What are you trying to print?

Comment: @RichardHeap I try to add authorization key into header, but when i send to the server, The server can not get the header of authorization.

Comment: Check that your server accepts the header name `authorization` in lower case. Dart will typically lower case all header name. Use Postman to confirm that a lower case header name works.

Comment: Just found the problem with server side checking header.  It's not work with `apache_request_headers()` on **Laravel**, need to use `req->request();`.

Comment: It's probably best to delete this question, as the solution is not actually related to the question. Your Dart code turned out to be correct.

Answer (score 48):

Dio library key working perfectly fine in my case if we pass **small case** key value

For example,

```
Dio dio = new Dio();
dio.options.headers['content-Type'] = 'application/json';
dio.options.headers["authorization"] = "token ${token}";
response = await dio.post(url, data: data);
```

make sure you write key in **small case**, that's work for me.

Comment: It's not necessary to write the keys in **small case**. It  is just case sensitive.

Comment: I am adding header in interceptors but now the request in not forwarding any more.

Answer (score 20):

In case of you use di in your projects and the dioclient is a singleton, this is how authorization is added to the call.

```
final response = await _dioClient.get(Endpoints.getDashboard,
          queryParameters{'shopId':int.parse(shopId)},
          options: Options(
            headers: {
              "authorization": "Bearer <your token>",
            },
          ),
        );
```

Answer (score 17):

There are some similar questions do not have answer 
But the following work for me 
Please use the following code snippet to set headers attribute

```
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer ${token}";
  response = await dio.post(url, data: data);
```

Comment: How to do the same thing when authorization is done using API key instead of token? @chunhunghan

Answer (score 2):

This work for me after try differents ways to pass the argument to headers

```
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    dio.options.contentType = ContentType("application","x-www-form-urlencoded");
    dio.options.headers[HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader] ="Basic $clientCredentials";
```

Comment: `The argument type 'ContentType' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.`

Answer (score 1):

That's probably bug because I was not able to set it with lowercase `content-type`.

`Content-Type` works.

```dart
options.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', ...request.headers};
```

Feel free to refer to https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/1045

Answer (score 0):

```dart
dio.options.contentType = ContentType("application","x-www-form-urlencoded") as String;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it like this:

```
_dio = Dio();
_dio.options.baseUrl = _baseUrl;
_dio.options.connectTimeout = 5000; //5s
_dio.options.receiveTimeout = 3000;
_dio.options.contentType = 'application/json';
_dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
_dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer 284|NRx1PaEY2HbwHi2XMzGdxg9UJ5rGXkNMcYyNXkqH";
_dio.options.followRedirects = false;
_dio.options.validateStatus = (status) {
  return status! < 500;
};
```