# How can I fix status code 302 in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, dio

how to fix status code 302 with flutter, this is my code

I used, headers and options: Options(
followRedirects: false,
validateStatus: (status) {
return status! < 500;
},
How can I overcome status code with Dio 302 in Flutter?

Comment: A 302 is a redirect. `followRedirects` should probably be true if you want to load the final destination.

Comment: In my case, I sent a `POST` API request using `dio` package, which returned an error `302`.

I issued an identical request using Postman, resulting in a successful response with a status code 200. However, when I attempted the same request in Flutter, it produced an error with a returned status code of 302.

I already solved this problem, please check my comment here if you did not solve the problem yet:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76972916/16449728